# This Universal Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines

I was reading [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/101815/98155) about Turing machines and it refers to a [bussiness-card-sized one](http://alvyray.com/CreativeCommons/BizCardUniversalTuringMachine_v1.6.pdf), which claims to be a universal Turing machine, based on [this paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0304397596000771/1-s2.0-S0304397596000771-main.pdf?_tid=ad635128-2171-44d4-b8df-7530c9177ad2&acdnat=1545527697_247df0cf4d988f260ff00d7ea0376dce). However, I don't understand the logic of that particular machine. I understand that in a universal Turing machine the "program" is just another machine encoded in the tape of the universal Turing machine. But, how is it encoded in this case? How would you write a program that adds two numbers for this machine, for instance?

Comment: Have you understood how UTM(4,6) in [that paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-3975(96)00077-1) is a universal Turing machine? Can you write a program that adds two numbers for UTM(4,6)? If not, those questions should probably be asked first.